# Is it possible to create a MVC application that navigates like Facebook?

Tags: facebook, model-view-controller

Facebook seems to have a single page where the content changes based on user interaction.

For example: If I click on somebody's post, the url changes to the user's profile/posts/.

Now I'm sure this is possible to implement on MVC.
Can somebody help me get started?
Perhaps some reference/sameple/tutorial (I believe this will heavily involve configuring the routings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's called Custom Routing.  You can set up custom routing in the routeconfig.cs file in your project (for pre-MVC4, routing is in Gloabal.asax).  Then you just use an Actionlink Helper to build your links.

Read More: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC